# Grouping boxplot together

Tags: ggplot2, boxplot

I have the following data and would like to create a group boxplot. I created a bargraph in excel and would like to create the boxplot in the exact same way using R ([see bargraph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kxV3.jpg)). I tried using `ggplot` but was unsuccessful. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Fruit    spring   summer  fall 
Banana   19.36    91.51   49.99
Apple    65.27     51.55  42.83
orange   16.21    94.71   62.33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you are looking for. To have the bar graph, you can do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!Fruit) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Fruit, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

Output

[image]

As far as a boxplot, you would need more than 1 data point, but if you wanted to do a box plot by `Fruit`, then you could do something like this:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!Fruit) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Fruit, y = value, fill = Fruit)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Output

[image]